# Field's side by side in the view Web2py

Tags: web2py

I'm working in web2py with fields, I searched if there was a one to have fields(inputs)
side by side instead of it being under one another. For instance

Instead of Author above Email, is there a way to have them side by side one another.

Comment: thanks for trying to help im pretty new to web2py i've searched spen but nothing useful came up could u explain please how would i do that.

Comment: Put the fields inside their own column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQLFORM()` takes a `formstyle` argument to specify different form layouts, but your case requires a custom layout. For that, see http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07?search=formstyle#Custom-forms.